# Django - view another user's profile - QuerySet Error 'matching query does not exist'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to set up a basic blog on django where one may view the profile of any other user (simple for the time-being, I will update perms in due course).

I've attempted to set it up so that url `/testuser/` would take you to the profile of user with `username = 'testuser'`. The url seems to direct ok, however, I'm getting a QuerySet error `'matching query does not exist'`.

I know that 'testuser' exists because I can access it in terminal using the same arguments as used in `get_queryset` in views.py below: `CustomUser.objects.get(username='testuser')`. Hence, I think there must be something wrong with my use of `get_queryset` in views.py, or similar.

Code as follows. Thanks in advance for any help.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from users.models import CustomUser


class ProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'profiles/self_profile.html'

    def get_queryset(username):
        return CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)

    def get_slug_field(self):
        return username
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:slug>', ProfileView.as_view(), name='self_profile'),
]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you try with 'CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username)' and tell me what is the output?

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh Solved. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Code below:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    template_name = ...
    model = CustomUser
    slug_field = 'username'
    context_object_name = 'profile' # for referencing in template
```